# Trying to rename files in folder with a vector file of names in r

Tags: r

I have a x number of .txt files in a folder that I want to rename using a list of names (a vector) in a variable.

I'm trying to develop a script that will rename all the txt files in a folder with a list of names stored in a variable that correspond to the original .txt files in the script.  I have gotten to a point where I trying to run `file.name()` with `sapply`.  I believe I'm not providing the correct "pattern", but I don't know what pattern to use.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Extract the headers of the sample table in the file.
headers <- read.csv(file="/mnt/data/Development/Sequences/SampleSheet.csv", skip = 18, header = F, nrows =1, as.is = T)

# Extract the sample rows.
sample.rows = read.csv(file="/mnt/data/Development/Sequences/SampleSheet.csv", skip = 19, header = F)

# Add the headers to the sample rows
colnames(sample.rows) = headers

# Extract the "Description" column which contains the actual names of the sample
newnames <- select(sample.rows, Description)

head(newnames)
# Define the directory where the sample files are.
startingDir<-"/mnt/data/Development/Sequences"

# identify all the samples (with ISeq-given names) in the folder.
tcr.sample <- list.files(path=startingDir, pattern="txt", full.names=TRUE )


head(tcr.sample)
# replace Iseq100 given names with Description name

sapply(tcr.sample, FUN=function(eachPath){

   file.rename(from=eachPath, to=sub(pattern="S._S.", replacement=newnames, eachPath))

})
```

Ideally, I should be able to change a series of file names from S01_S1.txt, S02_S2.txt and so forth through double-digits with names I store in the variable "newnames", for example, RK_ci1151_01.txt, RK_ci1151_02, etc.  The names don't necessarily follow a numeral pattern. I obtain the names from a csv column.  Each row has the original name of the file, and another column with the new name prefix.

Comment: I'm almost certain sapply() isn't going to work because one result I'm obtaining is that each .txt is getting an iteration of the vector.

Comment: if you think finding a correct pattern is difficult, i suggest you to check out a package named `rebus`, which provides a very flexible way (e.g., %R% pipe) to define any patterns you may find and works well with `stringr` package.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.